# Последовательность отношений в view

Tags: php, laravel, blade

Создаю форум на laravel, использую стандартный набор (Eloquent, Blade)
Задача такова:
Есть разделы, у разделов категории, у категорий темы, у тем сообщения.
На странице с списком категорий, выводится коли-во тем и сообщений в каждой категории. 
С темами всё работает

```
{{ $category->themes->count() }}
```

А вот с сообщениями выводит ошибку

```
{{ $category->themes->messages->count() }}
```

При этом, если перебирать циклом

```
@foreach ($category->themes as $theme)
    {{ $theme->messages }}
@endforeach
```

То сообщения выводятся (как и работает count). Но хотелось бы реализовать без циклов, возможно ли это и, если да, то как?

Comment: Неплохо было бы и сообщение об ошибке приводить в таких случаях. Из сообщения многое тайное становится явным. :)

Comment: ErrorException.Property [messages] does not exist on this collection instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может, все дело в том, что объект в поле `themes` не имеет поля `messages`? Насколько я понял из приведенного кода, `themes` - это коллекция, элементами которой являеются `messages` (которые в свою очередь являются коллекциями). Т.е. если сравнивать с массивами, то это эквивалентно двумерному массиву.

Предлагаю Вам рассмотреть возможность подготовить эти данные в контроллере и передать в view уже готовыми. В котроллере все же проще будет и `dd()` пользоваться для проверки данных в непонятных случаях.

Comment: Да, вы всё верно поняли. Вариант с контроллером я тоже рассматривал, но, тогда алгоритм будет такой: найти все темы категории, для каждой темы найти их сообщения и посчитать их кол-во. Т.е. это 2 объединения таблиц - что мне не совсем нравится, т.к. хотелось бы более изящное решение.

Comment: Ну, если я все верно понял - то без цикла никак. :) Вам надо просуммировать count() из всех messages, которые присутствуют в коллекции themes. А для этого их надо перебрать. Ну, или вытянуть результат из базы отдельным SQL-запросом как вариант.